# Encapsulation of functions | Purpose in terms of OO

Tags: javascript

Encapsulation is the core tenent of OO programming.

However, if you make a function private and then you return it so that you can use it, does this to anything effectively.

I would think not, that b.c. if you return a function , you are not returning a copy of it...you are returning a reference.  That is the core of the question.  When you return a function is it a copy or is it a reference to the actual function.

Does the code below keep func1 private and safe as good practice OO programming would like.

Or does encapsulation / data hiding not really pertain to functions?

```
var A = (function(){
    var func1 = function(param){
        // do stuff
        },
        publik;
    publik.retFunc(){
        return func1;
    }
    return publik;
}())

A.retFunc()(arg1);
```

Comment: Your example code has a few errors... syntax error in `A` (should `retFunc` be a function declaration?), and once you've fixed that, `A` doesn't have a method `retFunc`.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking, and it's not really clear what you mean by whether encapsulation "pertains" to functions or how one would judge this.

Comment: did you mean to put the evaluation brackets outside and next to the function declaration brackets?

Comment: "Or does encapsulation / data hiding not really pertain to functions?" — It doesn't pertain to contrived examples that expose everything that could be hidden.

Comment: normally you have getters and setters for accessing and mutating private instance variables ( encapsulation ).  I'm asking if this applies to functions as well.  I fixed the one syntax error.

Comment: ...i'm acutally using this for a framework that stores a single Controller in a private object.  I want access to this method from the public scope but i don't want the controller function mutated.

Comment: solution below is much more clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm really not sure where you're going with this...
But, to further the cause:

```
var Class = (function () {
    var private_data = 1234,

        private_method = function (x) { private_data += x; },

        public_method = function (x) { private_method(x); },
        other_method = function () { return private_data; },

        public_interface = {
            add : public_method,
            toString : other_method
        };

    return public_interface;
}());
```

I have now programmed to an interface.
This particular interface would be `.add` and `.toString`.

The private values are safe from tampering, as they've been enclosed.
`add` has the ability to access `private_method` so long as `add` isn't modified.

See, if you try to do something like this, after the fact:

```
Class.add = function (x) { steal(private_data + x); };
```

It's not going to work.
The new function doesn't have a reference to the private data.

So while an external person or program might tamper with the public interface, the internal state is still fine.

Your program will likely still break if it's been tampered with, or other, less protected classes might get compromised, but this one will sit happily, and any internal calls it needs to make (like if it updated a screen, on a timer), will still happen perfectly.

The other point of encapsulation is to choose the interface that you want to present to people.

You could have 30 helper functions inside of a class, but you probably only want to give the external application access to a few of them.
And those public methods will have access to the private data/methods, and the ability to do whatever it is you want the clients to be able to do, and nothing more.

That's an Application Programming Interface.

If I wanted to have a `BlogManager` class, it might be huge.
Maybe I want it to be able to get stuff from the database, to sort, to set up templates, or to communicate with a view...  I want it to be able to filter, I want it to do all kinds of stuff...

But I don't want the end-user to do all of that.
What I want the end user to do is `.request(options);` or `.create(blog_post);` or `.update(blog_post);` or `.delete(blog_post);`.

If I give the end-user those four methods then nobody can touch the dozens of other things going on inside of the BlogManager to make everything work as expected.
That's programming to an interface.

In the future, when I figure out a better way to filter my results, or when I change my database, or when I change the structure of the data-storage, it isn't going to matter what I do on the inside of my class, because the outside will still look and act the same.
If it has the same public methods, the same input-types, the same return-types... ...then you can do anything you want inside.

There aren't a lot of immediate cases for returning the ***actual*** constructor-function, instead of an instated object, though.

Much like there aren't a lot of cases for returning the function, instead of the function's return-value.
Aside from asynchronous programming.

Comment: Why wouldn't it? If you modify `Class.add = newFunc;`, then `Class.add !== public_method`. Meaning that `Class.add` will never have a reference to `private_method` ever again.

Comment: ... i had made the problem more difficult by returning a function from a functions instead of just calling the private function as you have shown.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist I'm not sure what you mean by "more difficult", you have simply exposed the private method, something which you didn't want to do. It's like saying, "I want to keep this secret, but I'll tell you anyway". Is it still secret? No, because you've purposefully given it away. Others can only know your "secrets" if you give them up.

Comment: yes...I have dumb moments thanks of pointing that out to Google and the World.